# Invert all characters in a string

Tags: java

I want to invert each character of my string and return each result in an ArrayList. This my code:

```
public static ArrayList<String> allInv(String word) {
    ArrayList<String> ListMotsInverse = new ArrayList<String>();
    ListMotsInverse.add(word);
    StringBuilder newWord = new StringBuilder(word);
    for(int i = 0; i<word.length()-1; i++){
        char l = newWord.charAt(i);char r = newWord.charAt(i+1);
        newWord.setCharAt(i, r);
        newWord.setCharAt(i+1, l);
        System.out.println(newWord);
        ListMotsInverse.add(newWord.toString());
    }
    return ListMotsInverse;
}
```

My result:

```
 ArrayList<String> resInv = allInv("abc");
 System.out.println(resInv);
 [abc, bac, bca]
```

But I want this result:

```
 [abc, bac, acb]
```

Comment: What makes `[abc, bac, acb]` preferred over `[abc, bac, bca]`? I don't know what you mean by "inverse".

Comment: I don't understand what OP wants.

Comment: I just want to switch the string.charAt(i) with the i+1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should reset your buffer to original state:

```
public static ArrayList<String> allInv(String word) {
    ArrayList<String> ListMotsInverse = new ArrayList<String>();
    ListMotsInverse.add(word);
    StringBuilder newWord = new StringBuilder(word);
    for(int i = 0; i<word.length()-1; i++){
        char l = newWord.charAt(i);char r = newWord.charAt(i+1);
        newWord.setCharAt(i, r);
        newWord.setCharAt(i+1, l);
        System.out.println(newWord);
        ListMotsInverse.add(newWord.toString());

        //reset to original state
        newWord.setCharAt(i, l);
        newWord.setCharAt(i+1, r);
    }
    return ListMotsInverse;
}
```

In your case you will switch two characters:

```
abc -> bac
^^     ^^
```

but there is no reset, so it will do:

```
bac -> bca
 ^^     ^^
```

And you expect:

```
abc -> acb
 ^^     ^^
```

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that you mean to get result like `[abc, bca, cab]` one of simple ways to achieve that would be creating another string which will duplicate original string and substring elements you want:

```
abcabc
^^^
 ^^^
  ^^^
```

like

```
public static List<String> allInv(String word) {
    List<String> ListMotsInverse = new ArrayList<String>();
    String text = word+word;
    for (int i=0; i<word.length(); i++){
        ListMotsInverse.add(text.substring(i,i+3));
    }
    return ListMotsInverse;
}
```

Comment: Does this produce bac or acb...?

Comment: @JaroslawPawlak It will return `[abc, bca, cab]`. I may be wrong but I suspect that this may be what OP wanted.

Comment: Agree with you, I dont know, if OP wants to swap character or "roll" the string  +1 @Pshemo